# Burninate [vw] and [vh] in favor of [viewport-units]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

With a combined 1 follower and 38 questions, [vh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vh) and [vw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vw) are certainly not used often. While creating this post, I checked and saw that 4 (of the then-42) questions were using these tags improperly (the tags relate to the CSS units).

I am *not* recommending an alias due to the lack of followers and apparent confusion.

Though [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) clearly says to only do one tag per post, these are inherently related. I feel it's appropriate to go all-or-nothing on the two of these.

## Burnination criteria:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It certainly could describe the contents, but no more so than [viewport-units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewport-units), which more descriptive. It's by no means unambiguous, as 4/42 questions were using it improperly.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, which is why I'm recommending retagging the questions (which I can do if desired).

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No more so than [viewport-units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewport-units), which also encompasses the `vmin` and `vmax` units. 32/38 questions are also tagged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) or [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3), and the remaining likely could have been.

[viewport-units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewport-units) already exists, and has 3 followers with 153 questions. I have not gone through those questions, but it is certainly more descriptive than [vw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vw) and [vh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vh). Only 3 questions with [vh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vh) or [vw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vw) are currently tagged with [viewport-units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewport-units).

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Apparently not, as 4/42 questions used it improperly.

Comment: Can we just synonymize them? I would think that it would be helpful to have `vw` and `vh` transform to `viewport-units`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think these tags are causing more confusion than they're worth. AFAIK, no other CSS units have their own tags, and there are dozens.

Comment: @jhpratt Well synonymizing wouldn't leave the around; if that happened, then any time someone tried to use the vw and vh tags, it would automatically switch to [tag:viewport-units]. The only problem with that solution is that if something comes along later that uses vw or vh as a name or abbreviation, it would have to use a different tag or be de-synonymized... but then it'd risk being used incorrectly by people meaning the viewport units. It's a toss-up, but I think with only 38 questions asked in ~2 years, there's not a lot of danger in just retagging.

Comment: There's an [em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/em) tag

Comment: Given that there are < 50 questions in these tags, you can follow the [abbreviated burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/3773011). However, you will need to get buy-in from at least one [trusted community member](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), which you don't have yet. That assumes "you have **authoritative** knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag".

Comment: Thanks @Makyen. I certainly know what I'm talking about when it comes to CSS units, so we'd just need a trusted member to give the ok before moving ahead.

Comment: @Makyen: For what it's worth, I upvoted TylerH's answer last weekend. Not that I'm authoritative or anything... I don't speak for the CSSWG.

Comment: @jhpratt Please see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 18):

Yep, no question about it; these should definitely all be re-tagged as [viewport-units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewport-units). It looks like two users just created the two tags in late 2016 and early 2017 without looking for [viewport-units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewport-units) which was created several years prior.

EDIT - I have handled this now. The [remaining question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009354/is-it-necessary-to-have-fallbacks-for-vh-and-vw) is closed and has no answers. It will be automatically deleted from the system by the Roomba (RemoveAbandonedClosed) by May 3rd, after which both tags should automatically be removed as 0-post tags from the system, too.

Comment: Assuming you mean _May_ 3.

Comment: @jhpratt Thanks, slip of the fingers there...